# Qt signal multiple definitions

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I don't understand, I have a header :

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QtQml>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <iostream>

class MainWindow : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString userName READ userName WRITE setUserName NOTIFY userNameChanged)

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString userName();

    void setUserName(const QString &userName);

public slots:

signals:
    void userNameChanged();

private:
    QString m_userName;
};
```

And the cpp :

```
#include "MyWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString MainWindow::userName()  {
    return m_userName;
}

void MainWindow::setUserName(const QString &userName) {
    std::cout << "SET USERNAME" << std::endl;
    m_userName = userName;
}

void MainWindow::userNameChanged() {
    std::cout << "UPDATED" << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile, I have an error :

/path/to/file/build/moc_MyWindow.cpp:169: error: multiple definition of `MainWindow::userNameChanged()'; MyWindow.o:/path/to/file/build/../project/Views/MyWindow.cpp:17: first defined here

I don't understand what is the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Don't define the signal yourself in the cpp, moc does it for you. (and with your version, no slots would ever be called)

Comment: You must not implement signals by your own.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld it's thank to the Q_PROPERTY macro (i'm a qt/qml beginner) ? If i want to have a specific behaviour for my signal what can I do ?

Comment: @chehrlic t's thank to the Q_PROPERTY macro (i'm a qt/qml beginner) ? If i want to have a specific behaviour for my signal what can I do ?

Comment: Signals are just the sending side of a notification mechanism with optional attached data. That’s all the behaviour they can have. Can you update the question with more details about what special behaviour you need and when (e.g. directly before sending the signal).

Comment: @besc ok i understand better, thank you

Comment: btw the usage here is pretty similar to the official example for signals/slots here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userNameChanged` is a `signal` not a `slot`. You can `emit` this signal anywhere you want, and there is no need to implement it. It seems that you want to emit this signal once a user name is set in the `setUserName` function. So do it as follows:

```
void MainWindow::setUserName(const QString &userName) {
    std::cout << "SET USERNAME" << std::endl;
    m_userName = userName;
    emit userNameChanged;

}
```

and remove the implementation of `MainWindow::userNameChanged()`.

Comment: pretty sure that should be `emit userNameChanged();`

Answer (score 1):

Don't define yourself the signal function, because MOC do that for you.